# Transition breaks angular flex-layout grid

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have a password checker and the angular flex-layout's grid works for it, but not if I want to transition. If it transitions at all all the content becomes in a column.

```
<div #passwordChecker class="password-checker" style="height:0;"
               gdAreas="lower upper | special length | number match"
               gdGap="15px" gdRows="auto auto auto">
            <mat-error gdArea="lower"></mat-error>
            <mat-error gdArea="upper"></mat-error>
            <mat-error gdArea="special"></mat-error>
            <mat-error gdArea="length"></mat-error>
            <mat-error gdArea="number"></mat-error>
            <mat-error gdArea="match"></mat-error>
```

the scss

```
.password-checker {
  font-size: .7rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.25s ease-in;
  width: 336px;
  mat-error {
    @extend .flex-vertical-center;
    color: var(--gray-700);
    i {
      margin: 0 .5rem 0 0;
    }
  }
}
```

and the javascript for the transition

```
@ViewChild('passwordChecker') passCheck: ElementRef;
showPasswordValidator() {
    this.passCheck.nativeElement.style = 'height: 5rem;';
  }
```

I have tried with regular div's, I have tried changing just about most css attributes in one way or another such as changing width and height. If I remove the in-element style attribute the grid seems to work and it comes out as intended, but once I activate the javascript to resize it for the transition it instead becomes a column and never fixes.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please post a working Stackblitz example. The technique works fine for me.

Comment: It's not a priority because I already made a workaround, but I think this may be a bug so I'll post it for the sake of the devs soon when I get a chance.